# Convert VB6 Open For Binary to VB.Net (Fixed String Array)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, binaryfiles, vb6-migration

I am trying to convert a VB6 app that reads a binary file.  I have listed the VB6 and the converted VB.Net code I am trying to use.  I have tried everything I can think of and I either get *Unable to read beyond the end of the stream* or *Cannot determine array type because it is nothing.*  Please help!

```
'####################  VB6 Code ####################  
Private Const DIGITALOUTS = 24
Private Const PAUSES = 8

Private PLabel(PAUSES - 1) As String * 30
Private EventLab(DIGITALOUTS - 1) As String * 20

Private Sub ReadFile()
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open "C:\TEST.BAT" For Binary As #FileNumber
    Get #FileNumber, 3000, PLabel            'automatic pausing instruction labels
    Get #FileNumber, 3500, EventLab          'digital output channel labels
    Close #FileNumber
End Sub



'####################  Converted VB.Net Code ####################  
Private Const DIGITALOUTS As Short = 24
Private Const PAUSES As Short = 8

<VBFixedArray(PAUSES - 1)> <VBFixedString(30)> Dim PLabel() As String
<VBFixedArray(DIGITALOUTS - 1)> <VBFixedString(20)> Dim EventLab() As String

Private Sub ReadFile()
    Dim f As Short = FreeFile()
    FileOpen(f, "C:\TEST.BAT", OpenMode.Binary)
    FileGet(f, PLabel, 3000) 'automatic pausing instruction labels <===Error: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream
    FileGet(f, EventLab, 3500) 'digital output channel labels
    FileClose(f)
End Sub
```

Comment: perhaps you should just use the BinaryReader class instead of converting the vb program into vb.net code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx

Comment: Agreed. Not all VB6 must be converted to VB.NET line-by-line. Microsoft put VB in .NET for a reason.

Comment: I get that but I need to get the data out of the file first.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out

```
Private Const DIGITALOUTS As Short = 24
Private Const PAUSES As Short = 8

Private Structure Pause
    <VBFixedString(30)> Dim Label() As String
End Structure

Private Structure Digital
    <VBFixedString(20)> Dim Label() As String
End Structure

Dim PLabel(PAUSES - 1) as Pause
Dim EventLab(DIGITALOUTS - 1) as Digital

Private Sub ReadFile()
    Dim f As Short = FreeFile()
    FileOpen(f, "C:\Test.BAT", OpenMode.Binary)
    FileGet(f, PLabel, 3000) 'automatic pausing instruction labels 
    FileGet(f, EventLab, 3500) 'digital output channel labels
    FileClose(f)
End Sub
```