# Wrap "Open" VB6 function with custom function as drop in replacement

Tags: vb6

### Question

**Is there any way to write a custom function that uses the same pattern as the Open function? Including the fluff keywords like `For` and `As`?**

[image: VB6 Help documentation describing the open statement]

### Background

I am working on migrating an old VB6 project to use online data via an API, as a first step I'd like to replace all instances of

```vb
Open SomeFilename For Binary Access Read As #39
```

With a custom `OpenOnline` function

```vb
OpenOnline SomeFilename For Binary Access Read As #39
```

But I do not know how to indicate those keywords are necessary when creating a function, or even if it's possible to do so.

```vb
Function openOnline(FileName As String) [For] (Optional Access As AccessType = Binary Access) [As] (Optional FileNumber As Integer) As Boolean
    ' Do the work of connecting to the online data equivalent of FileName with that access type
End Function
```

### Qualifiers

I understand that these keywords are nonsensical in the context of an `OpenOnline` function. I also understand that I can use regular expressions to find and replace the syntax to remove keywords like "For" and "Read".

There are hundreds of thousands of instances of this `Open` function, the `Put` and `Get` functions and a few other file related functions, I realize that long term the correct solution is changing the mechanisms fundamentally to use online paradigms, and that work is in progress- on schedule to be completed with about 4 months of effort at the rate things are going.

### Bonus Question

Secondarily, is there any way for me to pass a "User Defined Type" variable to the new Put/Get replacements in a way that I can access their fields directly without knowing the type beforehand? (I understand that variants are only available for .cls classes or public user defined types in dlls, neither of which apply in this situation)

Comment: As painful as it might be, I think I would lean towards changing the paradigm.  Plus, as mentioned by Hel O 'Ween in their answer, I don't know you can duplicate the Open syntax.  Which ever way you choose will have a significant time hit so you may as well code with the end goal in mind.  Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532445/convert-vb6-open-for-binary-to-vb-net-fixed-string-array) to give you some ideas.

Comment: I can't see how you could easily create a `customPut/Get(..., anyUDT)` as you hint at in your bonus question which may make the first question redundant.

Comment: Given the statement about using regexes - I don't understand the problem. Why don't you do that? I'm sure there are tools which could apply such a regex on an entire codebase at once; and with good use of source control you can positively (if tediously) verify that the changes were as you expected. So, why focus on replicating the original syntax?

Comment: I think the part about the UDT is an interesting question but probably should be asked separately.

Answer (score 0):

As for 1), you can get close but you can't *exactly* replicate the VB `Open` statement. Which means you won't get around of some search & replace passes for the current `Open` statement lines with your newly created one.

For 2), can you illustrate that with an example? I'm trying to think of a situation where you know the UDT member's name in advance, but not its type.

That said, perhaps looking at VB's [VarType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) function gives you an idea for solving that.

Comment: I think I'll have to ask the second question separately, my prior searches on the topic have lead me to believe it is also impossible.